# Ruby Begin and End Block usage

Tags: ruby

I have written the logic to find the "Bottle's Problem"

```
  module Bottle
      class Operation
        def input
          puts 'Enter the number of bottles:'
          num = gets.chomp.to_i
          bottle_operation(num)
        end

        def bottle_operation(num)
          while (num < 10) && (num > 0)
            puts "#{num} bottles"
            num -= 1
            puts "One bottle open. #{num} bottles yet to be opened."
          end
      end
     end
     begin
       res = Operation.new
       res.input
     end
    end
```

I was asked to use Begin and End block outside the module, since its not correct way to use. By doing so I got the following error

```
module Bottle
  class Operation
    def input
      puts 'Enter the number of bottles:'
      num = gets.chomp.to_i
      bottle_operation(num)
    end

    def bottle_operation(num)
      while (num < 10) && (num > 0)
        puts "#{num} bottles"
        num -= 1
        puts "One bottle open. #{num} bottles yet to be opened."
      end
  end
 end
end

begin
   res = Operation.new
   res.input
 end
```

> ERROR `<main>': uninitialized constant Operation (NameError)

What is the correct way to use begin and end block? how and where to use

Comment: The name must be fully qualified: `res = Bottle::Operation.new`.

Comment: thanks it worked, but Is it the right way to make use of Begin and End Functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct way to use begin and end block? how and where to use

Typically you don’t use `begin`/`end` at all.

The error in your code is that outside of the `module`, the class name must be fully qualified. That said, the following will fix the issue:

```
- res = Operation.new
+ res = Bottle::Operation.new
```

---

`begin`/`end` might be needed when:

- you need a block to be executed within `while` / `until` (credits to @Stefan);
- you want to `rescue` an exception;
- you want to have an `ensure` block.

The summing up:

```
begin
  puts "[begin]"
  raise "from [begin]"
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "[rescue]"
  puts e.message
ensure
  puts "[ensure]"
end

#⇒ [begin]
#  [rescue]
#  from [begin]
#  [ensure]
```

Comment: @mwp nah, indeed, thanks, fixed. I don’t remember much of ruby, should have checked against docs.

Comment: You could also use it to pack several statements into one expression. For example: `x = 2; y = begin puts "x is #{x}"; x end * 3`. It is not often this is useful, but inserting debug statements into expressions is one way to use it.

Comment: @Amadan yeah, I was almost to mention it, but IMHO it should be avoided in favour of `Object#tap`: `y = 42.tap { |x| puts "The answer is: #{x}" }`.

Comment: It's also useful in combination with modifier `while` / `until`, e.g. `begin ... end while condition` – this runs the body at least once, regardless of the condition.

Comment: @Stefan indeed, thanks, I have updated the answer with that one.